# WPF ComboBox & IsTabStop behavior

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox

I have a problem with `ComboBox` control on WPF.

I tried to set `IsTabStop` property to control but it don't works as expected.

If `ComboBox` is not editable, `IsTabStop` works correctly, but if `ComboBox` is editable it always take the focus from keyboard navigation.  `IsTabStop = false` has no effect!

Furthermore, when `ComboBox` is editable and `IsTabStop` is true, keyboard navigation to previous control is "locked"..."Shift+Tab" doesn't works!

Is this a WPF bug? Is there any workaround?

I'm using .Net 4.0.

This is an example...

```
<Window
   x:Class="MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Title="MainWindow"
   Height="250"
   Width="600">

   <StackPanel
     Orientation="Horizontal"
     VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <TextBox
        Width="50"
        IsTabStop="True">
     </TextBox>
    <ComboBox
        Name="cmb1"
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
        Width="50"
        IsEditable="True"
        IsTabStop="False">
    </ComboBox>
    <DatePicker
        Name="dp1"
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
        Width="50"
        IsTabStop="True">
    </DatePicker>
    <TextBox
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
        Width="50"
        IsTabStop="False">
    </TextBox>
    <ComboBox
        Name="cmb2"
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
        Width="50"
        IsTabStop="False">
    </ComboBox>
    <ComboBox
        Name="cmb3"
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
        Width="50"
        IsEditable="True"
        IsTabStop="True">
    </ComboBox>

   </StackPanel>
 </Window>
```

try to navigate with tab from first textbox to last combobox..."cmb1" take focus also with IsTabStop=False, "cmb2" is ok bacause it's not editable, on "cmb3" it's not possible return to previous control with Shift+Tab.

Also DatePicker seems have same issue.

Comment: can u give quick XAML to replicate that problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah seems to be the issue with ComboBox, somebody raised it with microsoft:

[Have a look here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/508705/wpf-forum-istabstop-property-stops-working-on-wpf-editable-combobox). It seems to have a workaround.

Here is a workaround.  In the Loaded event of your window/control place this code:

```
var textBox = myCbo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", myCbo) as TextBox;
if (textBox != null)
   textBox.IsTabStop = myCbo.IsTabStop;
```

Change myCbo for your combobox name.

Comment: have a look at workaround tab in the link provided, does that solve your problem ?

Comment: Okok...I solve. I've created a my CustomComboBox that extend standard ComboBox and on OnApplyTemplate method I've found the editable textbox and I've assigned IsTabStop property for textbox equals to IsTabStop of ComboBox.

Comment: For "Shift+Tab" issue, I've menaged it on KeyDown event of editable textbox...in this way:

Comment: if (e.Key == Key.Tab && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift && IsEditable && IsTabStop) { TraversalRequest tRequest = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous);
 UIElement keyboardFocus = this as UIElement;
 if (keyboardFocus != null)
            keyboardFocus.MoveFocus(tRequest);
 e.Handled = true; }

Comment: Link is dead.  Always best to re-post the relevant info along with the link so that link rot does not make your answer useless.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but I was looking this exact same issue up the other day. I found that `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"` solves the problem.

Comment: Nice. For the record I had to use TabStop="False" AND KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" to get this to work as expected. WPF being WPF again....